# UNIQUE constraint failed Django models

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, unique-constraint

I'm working on a Django webapp.

I'm trying to create a user from signup form.

I made sure that there is no user in DB with that username and entered data in signup form and hit enter.

There is a default language field that is populated with `txt` in User user model.

I'm using the following function to populate that field.

```
def get_default_language():
    lang=Language.objects.get_or_create(
        name='Plain text',
        lang_code='text',
        slug='text',
        mime='text/plain',
        file_extension='.txt',
    )
    return lang[0].id
```

But it's giving me the below error

```
IntegrityError at /signup/

UNIQUE constraint failed: djangobin_language.lang_code
```

Here is the code for **Language** model

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lang_code=models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name="Language Code")
```

Isn't it supposed to get or create the row in Language table? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: is this your complete Language model?

Comment: I believe `.get_or_create` attempts to get/create on *all* the fields you pass it... So if you already have something with `lang_code='text'` but with `name='not Plain text'` you'll get that... You can either get_or_create on just the unique field and then update the object and save it, or just try and get it, and if that fails, create the object... (I'm assuming you've missed off some fields from your language model posted here or I'd expect different errors...)

Comment: check column lang_code in Language table in database . delete record lang_code = "text" then try again . and use try except in function to prevent runtime error

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not complete. You.sre.passing different values for the get_or_create and because it can't find the exact object you are searching for than it tries to create one but the language code it's already used and you get the unique issue.

I suggest you to use a choices option on your language code field and pass a tuple with the ISO state definitions.

I also suggest you to retrieve based only the language code field and then decide or to update.the object based the other field passed or create a new language object. You must implement your own method to do that